# How can I find the @types/node changelog?

Tags: typescript, npm, upgrade

I use nodeJs 14 and I can see **@types/node** has a new version, which is a breaking change. Where can I find the **@types/node** changelog so I investigate these does not break my application? And do I really care as an applications developer for breaking changes on this package or should I only concentrate on the **typescript** package which as far I am concerned uses **@types/node** ?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the differences in the code by using this URL:

https://app.renovatebot.com/package-diff?name=@types%2fnode&from=14.17.20&to=14.17.21

Just adjust the `from` and `to` query parameters to your needs.